# Lead Breakup report for particular status

Tags: reporting, report-chart

I have a requirement to calculate the percentage of dead leads (where Lead status dead) against the total leads for a particular period. The report should only show the total leads vs dead lead count and percentage and not the other status of leads.

I created a report by grouping it by lead status and adding it to a chart with percentage.. but it shows breakup for all status but I just want to show the report for dead leads and not others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the report, double-click on "Add Bucket Field", add two buckets (Dead and Alive), add the Dead status to the Dead bucket, and the remaining values to the Live bucket. After changing to a Summary or Matrix report, you can then group by this bucket. You can read more in the [Using Bucket Fields](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_reports_bucketing_cheatsheet.pdf) (PDF) cheat sheet.